# Amortized Time Complexity of remove() Method in Java's TreeSet Iterator

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, treeset

What is the **amortized time complexity** of the [`remove()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#remove--) method when used with a `TreeSet` [`iterator()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#iterator--) in Java? For instance, consider the following code:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        set.add(i);
    }

    Iterator<Integer> iter = set.iterator();
    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(iter.next());
        iter.remove();
    }
}
```

I understand that the worst-case time complexity of `iter.next()` is `O(log n)` as it may sometimes traverse to the depth of the tree. The amortized time complexity of `iter.next()` is `O(1)`, given that the in-order tree traversal is `O(n)` in total. I also know that the worst-case time complexity of `iter.remove()` is O(log n) for the same reason. However, I'm uncertain about the amortized time complexity for `iter.remove()`. **I'm puzzled because when I use the iterator, locating the next target node in the tree takes only `O(1)` time. I'm uncertain whether the rebalancing step will consistently require `O(log n)` time.** Can you clarify?

PS: it's not the TreeSet's [remove()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html#remove-java.lang.Object-). TreeSet's remove must be `O(log n)` for sure.

Comment: View the source code, TreeSet uses TreeMap, and `iter.remove()` / `set.remove()` both should end up at a the same private call `TreeMap.deleteEntry()`;

Comment: It's a red-black tree, so `iterator.remove` *should* be O(1) amortized.

Answer (score 0):

The amortized time complexity of `remove()` with a `TreeSet` iterator is O(log n) due to occasional O(log n) restructuring during removals in a binary search tree.

Comment: However, Occasional O(log n) means worst case. It needs to prove that the number of this occurrence is order of O(n). Then the armotized time is O(log n). If the occurrence is O(1), then it is still armotized O(1).